# Checking if a value exist in a Pandas Series using 'in'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check if a value exists in a pandas series, However, I found an interesting fact:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['one', 'one1', '1', ''])
'one' in s1
False

'one' in set(s1)
True
```

Why wouldn't the `in` operation work for the Series object? Thanks!

Comment: Why is it necessary for Series to implement `in`? It's more or less a wrapper around `np.ndarray` which does implement `in` so just use `values` attribute of Series object.

Comment: Use `s.values` to check for strings.

Comment: @pavel Thanks. I was just purely curious since I thought it would be implemented for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` checks if **index** is in this series

```
In[29]: s1.__contains__
Out[29]: 
<bound method NDFrame.__contains__ of 
0     one
1    one1
2       1
3        
dtype: object>

In[30]: 'one' in s1
Out[30]: False

In[31]: 0 in s1
Out[31]: True

In[32]: 1 in s1
Out[32]: True

In[33]: 2 in s1
Out[33]: True

In[34]: 3 in s1
Out[34]: True

In[35]: 4 in s1
Out[35]: False
```